El formulario de registro no está pasando la validación en el lado del servidor
Estoy realizando un proyecto de autenticación.

Este es mi controlador de login

    public function login()
    {
        $rules = [
            "email" => "required|valid_email|min_length[6]",
            "password" => "required",
        ];

        $messages = [
            "email" => [
                "required" => "Email required",
                "valid_email" => "Email address is not in format"
            ],
            "password" => [
                "required" => "password is required"
            ],
        ];

        if (!$this->validate($rules, $messages)) {

            $response = [
                'status' => 500,
                'error' => true,
                'message' => $this->validator->getErrors(),
                'data' => []
            ];
            
        } else {
            $userModel = new UserModel();

            $userdata = $userModel->where("email", $this->request->getVar("email"))->first();

            if (!empty($userdata)) {

                if (password_verify($this->request->getVar("password"), $userdata['password'])) {

                    //Aqui contraseña
                    $key = getenv('JWT_SECRET');

                    $iat = time(); // current timestamp value
                    $nbf = $iat + 10;
                    $exp = $iat + 3600;

                    $payload = array(
                        "iat" => $iat, // issued at
                        "nbf" => $nbf, //not before in seconds
                        "exp" => $exp, // expire time in seconds
                        "data" => array(
                                    'id' => $userdata['id'],
                                    'email' => $userdata['email'],
                                    'role' => 4,
                                ),
                    );
                   
                   $token = JWT::encode($payload, $key, 'HS256');
                    $response = [
                        'status' => 200,
                        'error' => false,
                        'messages' => 'User logged In successfully',
                        'data' => [
                            'token' => $token
                        ]
                    ];
                } else {

                    $response = [
                        'status' => 500,
                        'error' => true,
                        'messages' => 'Incorrect details',
                        'data' => []
                    ];
                }
            } else {
                $response = [
                    'status' => 500,
                    'error' => true,
                    'messages' => 'User not found',
                    'data' => []
                ];
               
            }
        }
        return $this->respond($response);
    }


Este es mi formulario de login

            <form id="login-form">
               <fieldset>
                  <legend>Formulario de Login</legend>
               </fieldset>
               
               <div class="mb-3">
               <label for="login-email" class="form-label">Email</label>
               <input type="email" class="form-control" name="login-email">
               </div>

               <div class="mb-3">
               <label for="login-password" class="form-label">Contraseña</label>
               <input class="form-control" name="login-password" type="password">
               </div>

               <div class="mb-2">
                  <input class="btn btn-primary" id="submit-button" type="submit" value="Login">
               </div>
               
            </form>


Este es mi script de validación para login

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

    // Definición de la función de validación (sustituye a window.validator)
    const validateLoginForm = (form) => {
      const email = form.querySelector("[name='login-email']").value;
      const password = form.querySelector("[name='login-password']").value;
  
      const errors = [];
  
      if (!email) {
        errors.push("Este campo es obligatorio.");
      } else if (!/\S+@\S+\.\S+/.test(email)) {
        errors.push("Por favor, escribe una dirección de correo válida.");
      }
  
      if (!password) {
        errors.push("Este campo es obligatorio.");
      } else if (password.length < 5) {
        errors.push("Por favor, no escribas menos de 5 caracteres.");
      }
  
      return errors;
    };
  
    // Formulario de login
    const loginForm = document.getElementById("login-form");
  
    if (loginForm) {
      loginForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
  
        const errors = validateLoginForm(loginForm);
  
        if (errors.length === 0) {
          const formData = new FormData(loginForm);
  
          fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/login', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData
          })
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(result => {
            console.log(result);
            const token = result.token;
            alert("success");
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
            alert("error");
          });
        } else {
          alert(errors.join('\n'));
        }
      });
    }
});

Mediante Postman las peticiones se actualizan en mi base de datos.
Todo funciona correctamente. Sin embargo, solo login() funciona correctamente del lado Frontend, pero register() no.
¿Qué está mal?


Este es mi controlador de register

    public function register()
    {
        $rules = [
            "name" => "required",
            "email" => "required|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]|min_length[6]",
            "phone_no" => "required|mobileValidation[phone_no]",
            "password" => "required",
        ];

        $messages = [
            "name" => [
                "required" => "Name is required"
            ],
            "email" => [
                "required" => "Email required",
                "valid_email" => "Email address is not in format"
            ],
            "phone_no" => [
                "required" => "Phone Number is required",
                "mobileValidation" => "Phone is not in format"
            ],
            "password" => [
                "required" => "password is required"
            ],
        ];

        if (!$this->validate($rules, $messages)) {

            $response = [
                'status' => 500,
                'error' => true,
                'message' => $this->validator->getErrors(),
                'data' => []
            ];
        } else {

            $userModel = new UserModel();

            $data = [
                "name" => $this->request->getVar("name"),
                "email" => $this->request->getVar("email"),
                "phone_no" => $this->request->getVar("phone_no"),
                "password" => password_hash($this->request->getVar("password"), PASSWORD_DEFAULT),
            ];

            if ($userModel->insert($data)) {

                $response = [
                    'status' => 200,
                    "error" => false,
                    'messages' => 'Successfully, user has been registered',
                    'data' => []
                ];
            } else {

                $response = [
                    'status' => 500,
                    "error" => true,
                    'messages' => 'Failed to create user',
                    'data' => []
                ];
            }
        }

        return $this->respond($response);
    }


Este es mi formulario de register

            <form id="register-form">
              <fieldset>
                <legend>Registro de Usuario</legend>
              </fieldset>
               
              <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="register-name" class="form-label">Nombre</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="register-name" required>
              </div>

              <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="register-email" class="form-label">Email</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="register-email" required>
             </div>

             <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="register-phone_no" class="form-label">Número de Teléfono</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone_no" name="register-phone_no" required>
             </div>

             <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="register-password" class="form-label">Contraseña</label>
                <input class="form-control" name="register-password" type="password" required>
             </div>            

             <div class="mb-2">
                <input class="btn btn-primary" id="submit-button" type="submit" value="Registrarse">
              </div>
              
            </form>


Este es mi script de validación para register

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const validateForm = (form) => {
      const name = form.querySelector("[name='register-name']").value;
      const email = form.querySelector("[name='register-email']").value;
      const phone_no = form.querySelector("[name='register-phone_no']").value;
      const password = form.querySelector("[name='register-password']").value;

      const errors = [];

      if (!name) {
          errors.push("El nombre es obligatorio.");
      }

      if (!email) {
          errors.push("El email es obligatorio.");
      } else if (!/\S+@\S+\.\S+/.test(email)) {
          errors.push("Por favor, escribe una dirección de correo válida.");
      }

      if (!phone_no) {
          errors.push("El número de teléfono es obligatorio.");
      }

      if (!password) {
          errors.push("La contraseña es obligatoria.");
      } else if (password.length < 6) {
          errors.push("La contraseña debe tener al menos 6 caracteres.");
      }

      return errors;
  };

  const registerForm = document.getElementById("register-form");

  if (registerForm) {
      registerForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();

          const errors = validateForm(registerForm);

          if (errors.length === 0) {
              const formData = new FormData(registerForm);

              fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/register', {
                  method: 'POST',
                  body: formData
              })
              .then(response => response.json())
              .then(result => {
                  console.log(result);
                  alert("Usuario registrado exitosamente.");
              })
              .catch(error => {
                  console.error(error);
                  alert("Error al registrar el usuario.");
              });
          } else {
              alert(errors.join('\n'));
          }
      });
  }
});


ERROR DE CONSOLA:


{
  "status": 500,
  "error": true,
  "message": {
    "name": "Name is required",
    "email": "Email required",
    "phone_no": "Phone Number is required",
    "password": "password is required"
  },
  "data": []
}


segun se ve parece que no llegan datos ...

La cuestión está en que cuando se envía el formulario se pasan los name de los input para identificarlos, los cuales son diferentes a los nombre que intentas validar.
Por ejemplo el campo register-name
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="register-name" required>
Lo intentas validar con "name" => "required"
Para esto tienes que cambiar tu función así:
public function register()
    {
        $rules = [
            "register-name" => "required",
            "register-email" => "required|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]|min_length[6]",
            "register-phone_no" => "required|mobileValidation[phone_no]",
            "register-password" => "required",
        ];

        $messages = [
            "register-name" => [
                "required" => "Name is required"
            ],
            "register-email" => [
                "required" => "Email required",
                "valid_email" => "Email address is not in format"
            ],
            "register-phone_no" => [
                "required" => "Phone Number is required",
                "mobileValidation" => "Phone is not in format"
            ],
            "register-password" => [
                "required" => "password is required"
            ],
        ];

        if (!$this->validate($rules, $messages)) {

            $response = [
                'status' => 500,
                'error' => true,
                'message' => $this->validator->getErrors(),
                'data' => []
            ];
        } else {

            $userModel = new UserModel();

            $data = [
                "register-name" => $this->request->getVar("name"),
                "register-email" => $this->request->getVar("email"),
                "register-phone_no" => $this->request->getVar("phone_no"),
                "register-password" => password_hash($this->request->getVar("password"), PASSWORD_DEFAULT),
            ];

            if ($userModel->insert($data)) {

                $response = [
                    'status' => 200,
                    "error" => false,
                    'messages' => 'Successfully, user has been registered',
                    'data' => []
                ];
            } else {

                $response = [
                    'status' => 500,
                    "error" => true,
                    'messages' => 'Failed to create user',
                    'data' => []
                ];
            }
        }

        return $this->respond($response);
    }

O también puedes cambiar los name de los input.
Como nota adicional lo mismo está pasando en el login, envías el name diferente al que intentas validar.
